# Python/Pandas subtracting numbers in a column

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry if this is a dumb question,

I have a pandas data frame that looks kind of like this:

```
Col1   Col2

0      217
287    130
```

I'm trying to subtract the two numbers inside column 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `.sum()` the values in the columns and subtract that value from the first value at `df.loc[0]`

```
df
   Col1     Col2
0   0       217
1   278     130

df.loc[0] - df.loc[1:].sum()
```

The output:

```
Col1   -278
Col2     87
dtype: int64
```

If you only want to apply this to `Col2`:

```
df['Col2'].loc[0] - df['Col2'].loc[1:].sum()
```

Output:

```
87
```

You can use this on any number of rows in your data frame:

```
    Col1    Col2
0   0       217
1   278     130
2   23      45
3   22      123
4   370     123 

df.loc[0] - df.loc[1:].sum()
```

Output:

```
Col1   -693
Col2   -204
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to do subtraction between all of the elements in Col2, you can do:

```
sub = df['Col2'].diff()
```

sub will be a Series where:

```
Col2

NaN
-87
```

[DataFrame.diff()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

Comment: If you have more rows  `.diff()` will not keep subtracting. It will just show you the difference between two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you question you want to do this:

```
res = dataFrame['Col2'][0] - dataFrame['Col2'][1]
```

If this is not what you are asking please fix you question or comment below.

Comment: What happens if there are 10,000 rows in the Data Frame?

Comment: I think the question is simpler than that. The OP asks: I'm trying to subtract the two numbers inside column 2

I don't know why to put on the case of 10.000 rows if he only wants to substract two numbers. I accept that the question is a little ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry, although my question only asks for the two numbers in a column it would also be helpful to know how to subtract multiple numbers in a column as @JoeR said. My question was answered nevertheless, thank you for the reply!